# LISP Parser C++

Tags: c++, lisp, parsing

Is there an existing LISP parser written in C++?  I just want the parser, not a full interpreter, but an interpreter to go along with it would be a plus.

Comment: do you want a parser for s-expressions or for Lisp? Which Lisp? Scheme? Common Lisp?

Comment: I'm looking for a parser for a LISP-like syntax, so I guess a parser for s-expressions is really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Right, s-expressions are the syntax for Lisp data. Lisp programs are written using s-expressions. But not every s-expression is a valid Lisp program. So Lisp has more syntax on top of s-expressions. See the syntax definitions in the Common Lisp and Scheme standards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lisp is just a tree structure, any tree parser will parse lisp readily... you can try [this one](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/ho/node8.html) which google gave me.

Comment: In fact, the Common Lisp I write looks almost exactly like the parse trees I built in compilers class.

Comment: You can parse a subset of it easily. But the real thing involves more data-structures than just symbols and lists.

Comment: He did mention he wanted a parser, not a full interpreter

Comment: @DavidThornley  Indeed. :)  One could say, Lisp is basically an AST processor that has operations to modify itself.  Check out the famous 6.001 (SAICP) videos: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/

Answer (score 2):

[Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/bigloo.html) might be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

[Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org) is written in C, close enough?

Answer (score 1):

[XCL](http://armedbear.org/) is an implementation of Common Lisp whose runtime is written in C++. The compiler is written in Lisp but it has an interpreter written in C++ which is used for bootstrapping.